# Android : translate the language of whole app on click

Tags: android, localization, translate

I want my application supports Multi-language like as English, German, French..etc, so is there any example by which i can understand the flow and concept, to achieve it.

Thanks, Aditya

Comment: I think this link will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Localization for change language of all application..

just check [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: can you please tell me how to use google translate on button click in my application??

Comment: @Aditya1510 i appreciated your question.I am also looking forward an same requirement.Are you achieve this, please provides suggestions for me.