# How to make android app with option for Tamil and English?

Tags: java, android

In android app, within that app has settings option such as English and Tamil
If user select Tamil, with in the app only display in Tamil, in all activities all labels should in Tamil. if the user select English  all labels are changed to English. How to make that?

Please give any idea....

Comment: Just go to the following Link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022566/custom-multi-language-support/4873524#4873524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this Link: [Android : translate the language of whole app on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414435/android-translate-the-language-of-whole-app-on-click)

Then Do like this,  Add the string values for each locale into the appropriate file.

English (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">GoodMorning</string>
</resources>
```

Tamil, /values-tl/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Kaalai vanakkam</string>
</resources>
```

Link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: They provide other than Tamil language i need code for Tamil.  values-es / (here for spanish values)
can we use values-ta for tamil?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006280/translate-my-app)

Basically you have to put the translated Strings in a folder in the res folder.

Comment: In that link i have already referred. they didn't provide for Tamil code.

Comment: it would be in a folder called values-ta